# IOS/Android GPS Spoofing prevention

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, gps, core-location

I'm making an app that relies on the phone location for it to work properly, in the sense that it is a kind of game and cheaters would ruin it.

In android I think that is is simple to prevent this, because I will use gps location and also use Google Geolocation API, by using the cell towers id (I just need to confirm if the person is inside a city, don't need much accuracy). https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview

On IOS, I know that I have to prevent jailbreakers first. But even without jailbreak, how can I prevent people from faking their location? is CoreLocation non spoofed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Google Maps API doesn't use CoreLocation. It just uses the Location Manager that't built into the Google Maps iOS SDK. What are you trying to make that needs a reliable location?

Comment: I want to make a king of a game that gives you a crypto reward if you are in a certain region. But I don't want people to spoof gps and use emulators to get it

You didn't understand my question. 

In android to prevent this "cheats" I will get the network cells id's and use google api to confirm location (not spoofable)

But, IOS doesn't allow me to get the cell id that the phone is using, so I want some alternative to don't be tricked by gps spoofing apps or emulators